# How do I make a game play in a single monitor?

Tags: multiple-monitors, games

Recently downloaded Multiwinia and Darwinia, some old favourites, from a buy of the Humble Introversion Bundle. I'm running Ubuntu 12.04, and when I try to launch either game, it always stretches across both of my monitors -- pretty much unplayable.

How do I configure games to only run in a single monitor? I don't have an issue with any other programs -- Chromium, VLC, LibreOffice, etc. all spawn in a single monitor, and maximize within a single monitor when I try to maximize them.

Answer (score 2):

Games whose window you can resize you can put into a borderless fullscreen-window via:

```
wmctrl -r ":ACTIVE:" -b toggle,fullscreen
```

I put that in a script and bind it to a keyboard button, so that I can easily fullscreen all windows that allow resize.

Many games on the other side don't allow window resize, in those cases it's more tricky. I documented some ugly workarounds at (different issue, but it's caused by the same underlying problem):

[Prevent a fullscreen game from disabling the volume control keys](https://askubuntu.com/questions/257567/prevent-a-fullscreen-game-from-disabling-the-volume-control-keys/257841#257841)